# Changing value of control in TabItem makes TabControl change index. How?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a TabControl in a WPF project that contains seven TabItems.
In one TabItem (*TabA*) I have a ComboBox bound to a list of items. The selected Item is bound to a property in my code-behind. This works fine, and I can change the property perfectly.
In another TabItem (*TabB*), I can change that same property in another way. The ComboBox will therefore relect the new value.

The problem is that when the ComboBox in *TabA* changes it's SelectedItem due to the property changing from *TabB* - the `OnSelectionChanged` event somehow bubbles up to the TabControl, and raises the `TabControlSelectionChanged` event - even though nothing has happened with the tabs at all.

When I look at the arguments to the `TabControlSelectionChanged` event

```
var selectedTab = e.AddedItems[0] as TabItem;
```

selectedTab is null.

Why is this happening, and how do I prevent it occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the TabControl.SelectionChanged is the same event as a ComboBox.SelectionChanged.

I have already faced this problem once. To prevent this from occurring, I used this code:

```
private void myTab_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Source is TabControl) //if this event fired from TabControl
            {
                if (tabItemName.IsSelected)
                {
                    //Do what you need here.
                }
            }
        }
```

You can adapt this code for what you need. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Evil Str has answered the question, but after his lead, I found another method.
In the ComboBox `SelectionChanged` event, just prevent the event from bubbling further.

```
private void ComboBoxOnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // whatever code you want in here to handle the change of item
    e.Handled = true;
}
```